# WSO2 CEP Event Tables - How to see the records on an event table

Tags: wso2, wso2-cep

I am trying to check the events inside of an event table without joining it with an incoming stream of data.

Is this even possible in WSO2 CEP?

The following is not possivle:

```
from event_table select * insert into print_output_stream;
```

Is it possible to check the records on a WSO2 event table? something like a file or something like sql server management studio.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, it is not possible to read an (in-memory) event table without a `JOIN`, because;

When it comes to event processing, an action is taken upon arrival of an event. In other words, a query is written to be executed upon arrival of an event.

Therefore, it will only be required to take an action (in this case, read the event table) upon arrival of an event.

Hence a query cannot exist which does not get triggered by an event arrival.

As such, you will need a stream which triggers the action of reading from the event table (say *trigger_stream*)

When an event arrives to *trigger_stream*, you can read the event table by joining the event against the records in the event table **unconditionally**. In other words, you can omit the `ON` condition of the `JOIN` statement. By doing this, you will get all rows from the event table.

**Reading event table for debugging purpose:**

If your intention of reading the event table is debugging your Siddhi script, then you can remote debug Siddhi as you run WSO2 CEP server.